# Swift Charts - Display Different Charts with a Toggle

Tags: swift, charts, conditional-statements, toggle

What is the best approach to this? I want to display two different charts depending on a Toggle setting.

A simple version works:

```
           Chart {
                if isLineGraph == true {
                    ForEach(cloudCoverArray, id:\.self) {item in
                        LineMark(
                            x: .value("Date", item.date),
                            y: .value("CloudCover", item.averageCloud),
                            series: .value("Date", "CloudCover")
                        )
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.gray)
                        .lineStyle(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2))
                    }
                } else {
                    ForEach(cloudCoverArray, id:\.self) {item in
                        LineMark(
                            x: .value("Date", item.date),
                            y: .value("CloudCover", item.coverCloud),
                            series: .value("Date", "CloudCover")
                        )
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.gray)
                        .lineStyle(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1))
                    }
                }
            }
```

However if you try and make the charts fractionally more elaborate, like adding some line/rule marks, you get the "Compiler is unable to... try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"

```
Chart {
                if isLineGraph == true {
                    ForEach(cloudCoverArray, id:\.self) {item in
                        LineMark(
                            x: .value("Date", item.date),
                            y: .value("CloudCover", item.averageCloud),
                            series: .value("Date", "CloudCover")
                        )
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.gray)
                        .lineStyle(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2))
                    }
                    
                    RuleMark(x: .value("Date", cloudCoverArray[Int(daySlider)].date))
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.mint)
                        .lineStyle(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1))
                    PointMark(
                        x: .value("Date", cloudCoverArray[Int(daySlider)].date),
                        y: .value("Distance", cloudCoverArray[Int(daySlider)].distance)
                    )
                    .foregroundStyle(.orange)
                     
                } else {
                    ForEach(cloudCoverArray, id:\.self) {item in
                        LineMark(
                            x: .value("Date", item.date),
                            y: .value("CloudCover", item.coverCloud),
                            series: .value("Date", "CloudCover")
                        )
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.gray)
                        .lineStyle(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1))
                    }
                    
                    RuleMark(x: .value("Date", cloudCoverArray[Int(daySlider)].date))
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.mint)
                        .lineStyle(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1))
                    PointMark(
                        x: .value("Date", cloudCoverArray[Int(daySlider)].date),
                        y: .value("Distance", cloudCoverArray[Int(daySlider)].distance)
                    )
                    .foregroundStyle(.orange)
                     
                }
            }
```

Is this just a question of the best way handle conditionals within the main View?

Comment: create two different functions and call them according to your requirements instead of if else condition

Comment: Have functioned this. if isLineGraph == true {
                    chartAverage()
                } else {
                    chartActual()
                }

Getting an odd error "Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'" on the first function? If you rename it to the second function you get the same error? The functions are OK. Surely I should get the error twice, or not at all?